# Make an alfresco share site Taggable

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am aiming to make an alfresco site Taggable.

When creating a site, I am looking for a simple way (JS, XML) to let users assign Tags to a site.

It can be done by assigning Tags from Repository to the site folder, but what I want is to add Tag field to the site creation form.

Comment: What have you tried so far? For example, did you try customising the site creation form?

Answer (score 1):

Change the **create-site.get.html.ftl** use the *alfresco\components\form\controls\category.ftl* as reference to create the tags field.

Then change the **sites.post.json.js** in *org\alfresco\repository\site* and get the tags and add them to the site.

You'll probably also will need to change the client-site JavaScript **create-site.js** to send the actual tags value to the repository webscript.